# Merging list items python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

A python list consist of a number of items that is equally divided by 3.

The list looks like this:

```
the_list = ['ab','cd','e','fgh','i', 'jklm']
```

I want to merge 3 items at the time for the entire list. How should I do that? (the list could have any number of items as long as the number of items can be divided by 3)

```
expected_output = ['abcde', 'fghijklm']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the list while iterating an index over the length of the list with a step of 3 in a list comprehension:

```
[''.join(the_list[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(the_list), 3)]
```

You can also create an iterator from the list and use `zip` with `itertools.repeat` to group 3 items at a time:

```
from itertools import repeat
i = iter(the_list)
[''.join(t) for t in zip(*repeat(i, 3))]
```

Both of the above return:

```
['abcde', 'fghijklm']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a list comprehension and `range`:

```
output = [''.join(the_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(the_list), 3)]
```